# Om-next Remote Sync Tutorial send-to-chan

Tags: clojure, autocomplete, clojurescript, om

I am probably doing something wrong but I believe one of the [om-next tutorials](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Remote-Synchronization-Tutorial) has some issues; specifically the autocomplete example.  I was able to figure out [one of the issues](https://github.com/omcljs/om/issues/535) but there is another issue that is causing me some problems.

Once I put in more then two letters in the input box for autocompletion, the following code:

```
(defn send-to-chan [c]
  (fn [{:keys [search]} cb]
    (when search
      (let [{[search] :children} (om/query->ast search)
            query (get-in search [:params :query])]
        (put! c [query cb])))))
```

produces the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
core.js?zx=3jufl8vymlgw [452]   om_tutorial.core.send_to_chan
next.js [3034]  om.next.Reconciler.om$next$protocols$IReconciler$send_BANG_$arity$1
protocols.js [303]  om$next$protocols$send_BANG_
next.js [1656]  anonymous
```

I am not sure why this is the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck on [Slack](https://clojurians.slack.com/messages/om/) much of the development around om-next is experimental since it's still pre-alpha software.

Comment: yeah, that is what I read.  I posted on Slack and the IRC, but no one answered or said anything about it. I was going to post on the github link that I mentioned in my post since that help the helped my first issue, but they basically said the same thing, concerning Slack.  Super frustrating when you are trying to learn.  I guess I will just delve into the the om-next source code more (been doing that for a while now anyway) and try to figure out what is going on.  Thanks.

Comment: Treat it like a whole new language, with it's own primitives and rules. I'm trying to figure it out too, it's kind of a mind warp, you don't get to be like David Nolen in a few weeks.

Comment: True, true.  I was just figuring the 'official' tutorials would actually work. lol.

Comment: @user2517182 They don't. They have not been updated, and I understand this is not a high priority at the moment.

Comment: @nha I can see that now.  I guess the statement "This page is under heavy active development" means there is stuff on this page that does not work. :-).  Either way I figured it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but aren't you supposed to be in a `go` process to do `put!`?

Comment: @tolgap I do not have the slightest idea. lol.  I am still learning all of this stuff.  The code you see above is directly from the tutorial.  I am assuming they know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way to do things, but this is what I did to solve this issue.

1. Checkout om from github. (https://github.com/omcljs/om)
2. cd om
3. lein install

Now the latest om is available on your system.  (you can not just put it in your project file, because it is not on https://clojars.org/repo/ yet).

4. Now this is where I think the confusion happened for me.  Earlier in the
   tutorial, before the auto-correction example; there is a project file
   that is defined with `[org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha23"]`.  Then when the
   auto-correction example comes up, I used the same project
   configurations since there was no mention of how to configure the
   project file again.  It turns out that you have to use
   `[org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha29"]`.

Once that happens everything works although I get the following warning.

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `om_tutorial$core$AutoCompleter`. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
```

That will be a fight for another day.

BTW.
Since I used the older version of om originally, just installing the new one did not solve the problem.  `lein clean` did not solve the problem either.  I had to manually delete my `om-tutorial/resources/public/js` folder.  Then run `lein run -m clojure.main script/figwheel.clj`.

Comment: Hi, in my case, i get after upgrading to org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha29" an error: **Uncaught TypeError: uri.call is not a function** any idea why it can be that way?

Comment: @zavalit try using org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha29-SNAPSHOT"

Answer (score 0):

The error about each child array requiring a "key" prop has to do with React more than it does Om. React requires every subcomponent to have a unique id.

If you iterate over a factory method it won't generate a new id for each subcomponent automatically. You have to specify a key function:

```
(def app-state 
  (atom {:items [{:id 1
                  :title "Foo"}
                 {:id 2
                  :title "Foo"}]}

(defui Item
 static om/IQuery
 (query [this] [:id :title])
 Object
 (render [this]
   (dom/li nil (:title (om/props this))))

;; Specify key function as follows
(def item (om/factory Item {:keyfn :id})

(defui List
 static om/IQuery
 (query [this] [{:items (om/get-query Item)}])
 Object 
 (render [this]
   (dom/ul nil (map item (:items (om/props this)))))
```

The key function doesn't have to return a number, but it does have to return some kind of uniquely identifying piece of information for each item being iterated over (which in this case, the title is not).

Incidentally, you could also use `map-indexed` to generate a number to feed into the key function, or use a random number generator.

Comment: Thanks!  I am still getting the hang of all of this.  I will try to implement this information in the tutorial code and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is om.next/query->ast isn't defined in 1.0.0-alpha23 -- that was the source of the call on undefined error.

Here's a hacky work-around:

```
    (defn send-to-chan [c]
      (fn [{:keys [search] :as x} cb]
        (when search ;; e.g. [(:search/results {:query "xxx"})]
          (let [query (-> search first second :query)]
            (put! c [query cb])))))
```

Comment: Correcting my own answer: om.next.impl.parser/query->ast is the function, not om.next/query->ast as used in the tutorial.  Fix that and change onKeyUp to onChange in the search-field function and everything works.

Comment: just FYI: you can hit edit and change your answer without adding a comment (that people might not read). :-)